# Wiki markup in user macro with Confluence 4.0

Tags: macros, confluence

how can I use wiki markup in a usermacro (or something else which produces the dynamic output, done in the user macro editor), when using Confluence 4.0.
In Confluence 3.5.3 I had a macro with the following content, which I want to migrate:

```
{info:title=Table of content}
{toc}
{info}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found out how to solve this. You have to write XHTML, the following shows how the example above would look like in XHTML:

```
## @noparams
<ac:macro ac:name="info">
    <ac:parameter ac:name="title">Table of content</ac:parameter>
    <ac:rich-text-body>
        <ac:macro ac:name="toc" />
    </ac:rich-text-body>
</ac:macro>
```

Another dirty approach I found is to use the transition markup (may become obsolete in the future):

```
## @noparams
<ac:macro ac:name="unmigrated-inline-wiki-markup">
    <ac:parameter ac:name="atlassian-macro-output-type">BLOCK</ac:parameter>
    <ac:plain-text-body><![CDATA[
        {info}Here you can write wiki markup the old way, until Atlassian removes this transition markup (unmigrated-inline-wiki-markup){info}
    ]]></ac:plain-text-body>
</ac:macro>
```

Comment: Me to, I can understand that they had to change the persistence of the markup, in order to get their new full wysiwyg mode working - but it makes no sense to remove the wikimarkup from the user macros.

Answer (score 3):

To get the XHTML that you need to write for your macro, follow these steps:

1. Create a new page with the macro you want and save it.
2. If you are an *Confluence Administrator* or running in *development mode*, open the Tools > **View Storage Format** page.
3. The page will now show the raw output in the new storage format.

If you don't have access the **View Storage Format** option, then a workaround is:

1. Open the page Info (Tools > Info), take note of the `pageId=` in the URL.
2. Open a new browser window and enter the following URL, replacing the confluence root and page id variables.

`http://{your-confluence-root}/plugins/viewstorage/viewpagestorage.action?pageId={your-page-id}`

**References:**
[Confluence 4.0 Editor FAQ](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/DOC/Confluence+4.0+Editor+FAQ)

Answer (score 2):

You should just render the wiki markup into xhtml dynamically in your user macro! Here's some code:

```
## @noparams
#set($globalHelper = $action.getHelper())
#set($renderedhtml = $globalHelper.renderConfluenceMacro("{info}test{info}"))
$renderedhtml
```